# Rails 4: redirect_to :back and change/delete parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, query-string

I think this should be easy but I cannot for the life of me get it to work, or find anything on the web that explains it. After a form submit, I want to redirect back to the referer/referrer and alter or delete one or more of the query parameters.

For example, the form is at

```
/tasks/6?foo=1&bar=1
```

And I want to go afterwards to

```
/tasks/6?foo=0&bar=1
```

I tried all sorts of combinations based on

```
redirect_to :back, foo: 0
```

or

```
redirect_to :back, params: {foo: 0, bar: 1}
```

and so on, but nothing at all would redirect me to anything other than the original page. I was hoping to avoid having to mangle with the string myself, but it may come to that.

It would be awesome, too, if there were also a way to just get rid of a parameter altogether, e.g. redirect to:

```
/tasks/6?bar=1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:back` does not accept other arguments. In order to accomplish what you want to do, you need to get the value of the referrer using

```
request.referer
```

or

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Parse it with the `URI` library, extract the query and decompose it with [`Rack::Utils.parse_query`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb). At this point you have the hash of params.

You can update the hash, and construct the URL for the redirect.

Comment: That's what I figured I might have to do. What are the pros and cons of this approach vs a system where every form has a hidden redirect-me-here variable (i.e. locating the logic in the controller vs in the form)?

Comment: The solution with a hidden redirect me field would be a security risk: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#redirection